# Assign Class with if statement HTML

Tags: css, html, onblur, onfocus

im making a good looking login system, so i want to change the color of the text when something is entered inside the Form, but im not able to figure out how, i assigned them a class to make that work but it doesnt seem to work.

HTML:-

```
    <div class="Login">
                <form name="form1" method="get" action="index.php">
                <input type="text" value="Username" name="Username" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'Username'; this.class='Offline';}" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Username') {this.value = ''; this.class='Online';}">
                <input type="text" value="Password" name="Password" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'Password';}" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Password') {this.value = '';}">
                <input type= "Submit" Name= "Submit" value= "Login" class="Button">
                </form>
    </div>
```

and im changing the color in CSS on those classes. but it doest seem to work, can anyone guide me here, i dont have a lot of scripting experience in javascript, so i didnt want to go that side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`this.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) instead `this.class`

```
<input type="text" value="Username" name="Username" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'Username'; this.className='Offline'}" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Username') {this.value = ''; this.className='Online';}">
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCjQf/2/)

**Update**

You have to change the *condition*, as the condition wasn't satisfying and class wasn't applied:

```
<input type="text" value="Username" name="Username" onblur="if (this.value != '') <-- Here {this.value = 'Username'; this.className='Offline'}" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Username') {this.value = ''; this.className='Online';}">
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zCjQf/3/)

Comment: It seems to be working when i change the background, how do i change the font color

Comment: @SahilSingh Use only `color:...` instead of `background-color`

Comment: the color does not change like that for some reason, im able to do everything with the font except change color

Comment: hey man, thanks it worked, im having some more trouble how do i set the default color of the text

Answer (score 0):

Use [this.className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) instead of `this.class`

```
 <input type="text" value="Username" name="Username" onblur="if (this.value === '') {this.value = 'Username'; this.className='Offline';}" onfocus="if (this.value === 'Username') {this.value = ''; this.className='Online';}">
```

[JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4tNQH/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Jquery?

```
$(this).attr('class','yourclass');
```

or

```
$(this).removeClass('Offline');
$(this).addClass('Online');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use setAttribute and getAttribute methods instead of class or className properties.